# Foundation sticky navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sass, zurb-foundation

I have an issue with the sticky navigation from foundation.

I have the following HTML code:

```
<div data-sticky-container>
    <div class="title-bar sticky" data-sticky data-options="marginTop:0; stickTo:top;">
        text nave something
    </div>
</div>

<div style="height: 2000px;">
    lorem ipsum text here lorem ipsum text here lorem ipsum text here lorem ipsum text herelorem ipsum text herelorem ipsum text herelorem ipsum text herelorem ipsum text herelorem ipsum text herelorem ipsum text herelorem ipsum text herelorem ipsum text herelorem ipsum text here
</div>
```

I have the following sass code:

```
.sticky-container {
    position: relative;
    background: #ff0;
}

.sticky {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.sticky.is-stuck {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 5;

    &.is-at-top {
        top: 0;
    }

    &.is-at-bottom {
        bottom: 0;
    }
}

.sticky.is-anchored {
    position: relative;
    right: auto;
    left: auto;

    &.is-at-bottom {
        bottom: 0;
    }
}
```

And calling foundation like this in javascript:

```
$(document).foundation();
```

I want to use the built in functionality of foundation for the sticky navigation, but I don't want to add the entire css file which is:

```
<link rel=stylesheet href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.2.3/foundation.min.css">
```

As you will be able to see in this code pen example (http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ggaXem) the **sticky** navigation doesn't receive the class **"is-stuck"** and the fixed styling doesn't work.

I can not figure out what is so special in that css file and what makes it tick, I debugged for hours and can't figure out what I'm missing.

I need that **is-stuck** class to do some other styling to children.

The help will be much appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: you can try jQuery function for add and remove "is-stuck" class on scroll. And add background on title-bar class. [ https://jsfiddle.net/tjbaezid/Lomx8y4c/ ]

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion  Mostafa, but If I won't find a solution soon, as a last resort I will load the foundation css, but I don't want to do any javascripts tricks.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I managed to find out that if I add in my SASS file the following line:

```
.foundation-mq {
    font-family: "small=0em&medium=40em&large=64em&xlarge=75em&xxlarge=90em";             
}
```

Everything would work just fine.
To find this fix I decomposed the entire CSS file from foundation.

Thank you to whom tried to help.